# sqlite3_open_v2 SQLITE_OPEN_NOFOLLOW flag not working on windows

Tags: c++, sqlite

We are using sqlite3 library in c++ to access sqlite database. Our requirement is that, if a db file is a symlink, we should not read/write to it. We are using the following:

```
sqlite3_open_v2(dbFilePathStr.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_NOFOLLOW, NULL)
```

This works on Mac but on windows, our app is still able to Read/Write to symlink db files. Is there a limitation to SQLITE_OPEN_NOFOLLOW flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick trawl through the sqlite Windows-specific VFS code, it does nothing to check if a given filename is a symbolic link or not, making that option a no-op on Windows.